# Не отправляется письмо с почтового сервера yandex

Tags: django, веб-программирование, smtp

Делаю форму регистрации для интернет магазина, в качестве подтверждения нужно подтвердить email.
Отрывок файла settings.py:

```
# ADDED EMAIL-SERVER
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'otherstest@yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
SERVER_EMAIL = 'otherstest@yandex.ru'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'otherstest@yandex.ru'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

мой отрывок кода в views:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        try:
            z = 0
            #User.objects.create_user(username=data['email'], first_name=data['name'], last_name=data['surname'],
                                     #password=data['password'])

        except:
            return render(request, 'base/registration.html',
                          context={'form': form, 'message': 'User with this email is already registered'})
        else:
            send_mail(
                subject='Login in Others',
                message='Please login',
                from_email='otherstest@yandex.ru',
                recipient_list=[data['email']]
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        return render(request, 'base/registration.html', context={"form": form})
```

При отправке формы сайт показывает загрузку, но ничего не происходит, просто загрузка, никаких ошибок не выдает.
Мои настройки в самой почте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решение крылось в изменении одной строчки, а именно

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True на EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Знатоки, не могли бы вы пояснить, почему с SSL работает, а c TLS нет?